# Understanding Command Pattern and why do we need an interface?

Tags: java, android, command-pattern

I am trying to reduce the if else constructs which I use to display appropriate information in a ListView (Android)

I have created a simple Command Interface for learning purpose and here it is:

```
interface CommandPattern {
    void execute();
} 

public class CommandA implements CommandPattern {
    public void execute(){
        System.out.println("I am Command A");
    }
}

public class CommandB implements CommandPattern{
    public void execute(){
        System.out.println("I am Command B");
    }
}
```

Then my Main is as follows:

```
public class MainClass {
    static Map<String,CommandPattern> myCommand; //= new Map<String, CommandPattern>();
    public static void main(String[] args){
        myCommand = new HashMap<String, CommandPattern>();
        myCommand.put("A",new CommandA());
        myCommand.put("B",new CommandB());

        // In an ideal condition I will invoke the below by supplying values I get from the Database
        // myCommand.get(valuefromDB).execute();


        myCommand.get("B").execute();
        myCommand.get("A").execute();
    }
}
```

What I have done above can be achieved without using the interface and extending from one by simply calling the execute method of an appropriate class. What is the reason of using an interface?

Secondly does it mean that for each if - else branch I have to construct a new class? Cant this be done using an enum?

The background of the problem:

I have a database and I fetch values based on this data anda number of flags I process data to be displayed in each row. This if else construct has gone beyond what I can ever maintain. So I want to introduce a Command pattern.

Comment: Which if/else constructs are you trying to eliminate. You should read up on the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern before using it. Generally it should be used when you want to repeat a sequence of actions, e.g. when implementing macros or an undo function. This does not seem to be applicable in your case.

Comment: I have a database and I fetch values based on these values and on a number of flags I process data to be displayed in each row. This if else construct has gone beyond what I can ever maintain. So I want to introduce a Command pattern.

Comment: A simple example would be expecting any values from 1 to 10 coming from the database and it can well fit into the pattern as developed above. So based on these values I can direct the program to execute any of the execute functions as listed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing an interface: ClassA has some behavior (i.e., one or more methods), defined by an InterfaceB, that it supports.

Extending a class says that ClassA is a 'special case' of the ClassB being extended; i.e., that ClassA has all of the characteristics (data and methods) of ClassB plus additions and/or changes.

You can implement the Command pattern with either one; which one is appropriate depends on the specific situation.  What is to be avoided is using inheritance where the 'special case' does not apply; put another way, do not use inheritance just to have a common method among classes.

EDIT: as to "Can't this be done using an Enum?", it isn't clear what you mean by 'this'.

Comment: Instead of using multiple classes for each branch, cant I use an enum?

Comment: this is not specific enough to answer.  Use multiple classes how?  Use an enum how?  When you're asking programming questions, especially on the web like this, you have to give the context and the situation that we have no other way of figuring out...

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate the power of using an interface:

```
public class MainClass {
    static List<CommandPattern> myCommand; 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        myCommand = new ArrayList<>();
        myCommand.add(new CommandA());
        myCommand.add(new CommandB());

        for (CommandPattern command: myCommand) {
            command.execute();
        }

    }
}
```

This example shows that two different commands can be executed using the interface. The for-loop is only aware of the fact that it can call `èxecute()` on the object, but the actual code being executed varies depending on the concrete object adhering to the interface.

Since it is if-else branching you wish to get rid of, I think you might want to look into the Strategy Pattern as well.

Comment: Actually I need a mix of this Command pattern and Strategy pattern because there is nesting of if-else conditions. But I dont want make so many classes because the end goal is to display in views and as I am using a listView I am implementing a view holder pattern and getting handlers to views is going to be tedious in different classes.